# Is this copy constructor creating an identical and independent deep copy of the input object?

Tags: c++, list, constructor, copy

I have the following copy constructor made for a Polynomial class.  The constructor is supposed to create an independent deep copy of the input Polynomial object.  Is the copy constructor actually doing this or is it creating a shallow copy?

```
Polynomial::Polynomial(const Polynomial &p) {
    cout << "Enter method\n";
    if(p.head != NULL) {
        cout << "Enter if\n";
        Node* n = p.head;

        int nDegree = n->degree;
        while(n != NULL) {
             this->add(n->coeff, n->degree);
             nDegree--;
             n = n->next;
        }
        n = NULL;
    }   
}
```

Here is the add method:

```
void Polynomial::add(const float& coeff, const int& degree) { 
    Node *temp = new Node(coeff, degree, NULL, NULL);
    temp->coeff = coeff;
    temp->degree = degree;
    if(tail == NULL) {
        head = temp;
        tail = temp;
        arrSize++;
    }
    else {
        temp->prev = tail;
        tail->next = temp;
        tail = temp;
        arrSize++;      
    } 
 }
```

Comment: You didn't provide enough information to answer the question. Show the class definition and the other constructors, at least

Comment: _@user2932450_ Next time you post code snippets here, [**please ensure**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26026984/revisions) you don't have any TAB characters (`\t`) in the literal text.

Comment: Why are you setting the coefficient and degree twice in the add() method?

Answer (score 1):

`Polynomial::add()` creates a new node and inserts it in a linked list.

Your copy constructor iterates through the existing linked list to add notes to the list being consutructed.

So it's a deep copy and not a shallow copy.

**Remarks:**

Consider initializing explicitey `head` an `tail` to `NULL` in your copy constructor, before starting to add nodes.

Depending on the `Node` constructor, apparently using `coeff` and `degree` you may consider not to redundantly reassign these values to `temp` members.

The purpose of `nDegree--;` in your loop is not completely clear to me.  I think you could drop it.